# Clone content w/javascript from elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, code-duplication

I have very little JavaScript knowledge and have been tasked with duplicating an H2 and a P from a DIV into another DIV that shows on a hover.  Please take a look at what I'm trying to do here: http://dev.surgeryatnmc.org/surgical-services/.

I'm trying to clone from .orig to .hover, and it's sort of working but showing all three live items in each tooltip instead of individually.

Here are my list items:

```
<ul>
    <li class="lactrimal1">
                <div class="orig">
                    <h2>Lactrimal Duct Probe</h2>
                    <p>Helps patient regain use of their tear ducts in this quick procedure.</p>
                </div>                    
                <div class="img">
                    <div class="txt hover"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="cataracts2">
                <div class="orig">
                    <h2>Cataracts</h2>
                    <p>We replace the eye's natural lens which has become clouded by cataract with an artificial lens.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="img">
                    <div class="txt hover"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="sinus3">
                <div class="orig">
                    <h2>Endoscopic Sinus Surgery</h2>
                    <p>A procedure used to remove blockages in the sinuses to allow for efficient pain-free breathing.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="img">
                    <div class="txt hover"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Here's my script:

```
$('div.orig', this).each(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('div.hover');
});
```

I've also tried this but it only clones the first item:

```
$(".hover").html($('.orig').html());
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks everyone!

**All of your answers worked, I didn't realize there could be so many solutions to the issue.  thanks a ton for the help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.orig').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.txt').html( $(this).html() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

EDIT:
Actually you have to do like so to get to the element

```
$('div.orig').each(function() {
    var jThis = $(this);
    jThis.parent().find('.hover').html(jThis.html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.orig', this).each(function() {
    $(this).next('.img').children('.hover').html($(this).html());
});
​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S2Nhw/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo! That Fiddle site is great too

Answer (score 0):

anpother solution->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.orig', this).each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('div.hover:eq(' + i + ')');
});
})​
```